# О количестве слов в русском и английском языках

Tags: лексика

**Можно ли согласиться со следующей информацией из  Интернета или она в чем-то ошибочна?**

"Если сравнить русский и английский словари, то  видно, что мы проигрываем по числу слов английскому языку: Большой академический словарь русского языка содержит (около) **150 тысяч слов**, среди которых не менее 30% заимствованных слов; а Вебстеровский словарь (самый полный словарь  английского языка) содержит примерно **450 тысяч слов.**

Получается, что реальность англоговорящих богаче по восприятию, чем у русскоговорящих. И это значит, что ресурс (у нас, по-видимому!)  в понимании себя и мира есть, и большой. И потенциал реализации этого ресурса тоже есть – ведь английские слова активно проникают в русский язык".

**Хотелось бы услышать обоснованные возражения на эту тему, так как такой вывод не кажется мне корректным.**

Как-то странно реальность и духовность народа оценивать **по общему** количеству слов в языке. Может быть, надо учитывать и значения слов тоже (то есть качество словарного состава).

Comment: [Что у нас с БАСом?](https://rg.ru/2014/10/10/slovari.html) Почитайте эту статью. В ней автор БАСА рассказывает о принципах создания словарей.

Comment: Зачем вообще оценивать духовность народа по его языку? Где связь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В каком языке больше слов в русском или английском сказать нельзя, так как  для этого их нужно привести в одну систему подсчёта. Дело в том, что если в английском зафиксируют любое новое слово, то у нас оно должно попасть в литературный язык. Поэтому в английских словарях можно найти слово *Web2.0*, а в русских даже "троллинга" может не оказаться.
Второе отличие в том, что у нас словарь начинается с Пушкина, а в английском с Шекспира, что добавляет английскому ещё кучу, неиспользуемых ныне архаизмов.

Ну, и наконец самое важное. Из всего этого богатства языка, даже хорошо образованные люди используют не более 20 тыс. слов, так что количество слов в любом языке не имеет особого значения, в виду ограниченности его носителей.

Comment: Спасибо, очень убедительно.

Comment: Марк Из, вы несколько заблуждаетесь в отношении того, что "сказать нельзя". Просто для этого совсем не надо изобретать какую-то систему подсчета. Достаточно оценить по любой известной. Я вот дал привел с переводами. Случаев неоднозначного перевода с русского на английский неизмеримо больше, чем в обратную сторону. Чтобы это понять, не н7адо искать точных цифр.

Comment: *так что количество слов в любом языке не имеет особого значения, в виду ограниченности его носителей.* - а вот этого совсем не понял. Какие-таки ограниченные носители? И "не имеет значения" - это смотря для чего. Нет?

Comment: @behemothus это к тому, что для мировосприятия не важно сколько сотен тысяч слов в языке, если его носители используют лишь от 2 до 20 тыс. слов.

Comment: @МаркИз Т.е. вы понимаете под "носителями" круг лиц, использующих данное слово, А ограниченность - небольшое их количество? Если да, то не думаю, что вас легко понять... Ну допустим, а почему это не имеет значения-то для мировосприятия? И чьего мировосприятия?

Comment: Вообще я думаю, что в какой (немалой) степени на мировосприятие индивидуума влияние оказывает его ***пассивный*** словарный, а вот он-то как раз весьма коррелирует с общим числом слов в языке. Но тут надо оговориться, что я не имею в виду прямую "влияние" типа "чем больше пассивный запас, тем богаче внутренний мир".  Т.е это самое мировозрение дикаря и интеллектуала-полиглота не лучще и не хуже одлин другого. Просто они разные. Принципиально разные. Вот как-то   так.

Comment: Под "носителями" я понимаю носителей языка. Что носитель английского, что носитель русского будет использовать одинаковое количество слов. То сколько слов своего языка они не знают на мировосприятие влиять не должно, поэтому тезис автора вопроса о большем богатстве англоговорящего выглядит сомнительным.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибочно!

Мы побеждаем не числом, а уменьем

образовывать новые слова от имеющихся корней!

Мы можем нанизывать корни (автомотовелофототелерадиомонтер, бальнеогрязелечебница, биомагнитогидродинамика, водогазонепроницаемый),

не говоря уж о приставках (непредусмотрительный, предрасположенный, порасспрошенный, прапрапрапрадедушка),

вот слова с тремя суффиксами (примеры):

> веселить — увеселить — увеселительный — увесел-и—тельн-о; форма —
>   оформить — оформитель — оформ-и—тель—ниц-а;  маска — маскировать —
>   маск-ир—ов—к-а; знать — познать — познавать — познавательный —
>   позна-ва—тельн—ость; старый — стареть — устареть — устарелый —
>   устар-е—л—ость; диво — удивить — удивительный — удив-и—тельн—о; учить
>   — учитель — уч-и—тель—ниц-а; лук — луковый — луковица —
>   лук-ов—ич—н-ый; скука — скучный — скучноватый — скуч-н—оват—о,

и так до бесконечности.

[Самые длинные слова в русском языке:](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0/)

> «Тетрагидропиранилциклопентилтетрагидропиридопиридиновые» (55 букв,
>   химич. вещество)
>
> «Гидразинокарбонилметилбромфенилдигидробенздиазепин» (50 букв,
>   транквилизатор Гидазепам)
>
> «Кокамидопропилпропиленгликольдимонийхлоридфосфат» (48 букв,
>   химическое вещество)
>
> «метоксихлордиэтиламинометилбутиламиноакридин» (44 буквы, химическое
>   вещество, другое название — акрихин)
>
> «четырёхсотпятидесятисемимиллиметровое» (37 букв, ствол орудия)
>
> «превысокомногорассмотрительствующий» (35 букв, самое длинное русское
>   слово, зарегистрированное в «Книге рекордов Гиннесса» издания 2003
>   года)
>
> «рентгеноэлектрокардиографического» (33 буквы)
>
> «тифлосурдоолигофренопедагогика» (30 букв, педагогический термин)
>
> «фиброэзофагогастродуоденоскопия» (31 буква, медицинская
>   диагностическая процедура)
>
> «водогрязеторфопарафинолечение» (29 букв)
>
> «автоэлектростеклоподъемники» (27 букв)
>
> Самая длинная лексема — геологический термин
>   «уплощенно-пинакоидально-ромбоэдрический» (37 букв и 2 дефиса,
>   зафиксирована в «Книге рекордов Гиннесса»).

Архаизмы, диалектизмы и историзмы, жаргонизмы плюс неологизмы и всяческие окказионализмы, которым несть числа!

*ВМПС им. Тургенева* - в каком словаре найдёшь сей аксёновский шедевр?!

Вот у Веллера только что прочла слово "университетскость" (которую ему не прощали), - и где это слово зафиксировано?

---

> «Скрымтымным» — это пляшут омичи?
>
> скрип темниц? или крик о помощи?
>
> или у Судьбы есть псевдоним,
>
> темная ухмылочка — скрымтымным?
>
> ---
>
> Скрымтымным — то, что между нами.
>
> То, что было раньше, вскрыв, темним.
>
> «Ты-мы-ыы...» — с закрытыми глазами
>
> в счастье стонет женщина: скрымтымным.
>
> ---
>
> Скрымтымным — языков праматерь.
>
> Глупо верить разуму, глупо спорить с ним.
>
> Планы прогнозируем по сопромату,
>
> но часто не учитываем скрымтымным.
>
> ---
>
> «Как вы поживаете?» — «Скрымтымным...»
>
> Из-за «скрымтымныма» закрыли Крым.
>
> ---
>
> Скрымтымным — это не силлабика.
>
> Лермонтов поэтому непереводим.
>
> Лучшая Марина зарыта в Елабуге.
>
> Где ее могила? — скрымтымным...
>
> ---
>
> А пока пляшите, пьяны в дым:
>
> «Шагадам, магадам, скрымтымным!»
>
> Но не забывайте — рухнул Рим,
>
> не поняв приветствия: «Скрымтымным».

Answer (score 4):

Слушала курс Светланы Тер-Минасовой "Язык, культура и межкультурная коммуникация", там затрагивалась похожая тема. Вообще речь шла о том, что первично: язык или культура; кто из них кого формирует, а кто - формируется.

Естественный вывод: язык формирует культуру, а культура - язык. В одно и то же время мы оказываемся и заложниками и творцами, мы мыслим образами, но выражаемся словами и это загоняет в определённые рамки, которые - ! - мы сами и создаём. Забавненько.

Это я к тому, что, действительно, язык с культурой связаны очень-очень тесно и поэтому нужно рассматривать их в совокупности. Отличаются ли наши культуры? Да, разумеется, причём очень сильно. Поэтому русский сильно отличается от английского, в том числе и способом выражения мысли. Возьмём самый простой пример:

*Я лягушка. (I am a frog)*

Уже по одному предложению видно, что нам требуется в два раза меньше слов, чтобы выразить одну и ту же мысль. (Забавно, кстати, получилось - в обоих случаях по четыре слога...)
При этом чаще всего русские переводы английских текстов получаются длиннее, чем оригиналы.

Но это уравнивается в других местах. Ещё один наипростейший пример: *синий-голубой (синеватый-голубоватый)* и... *blue*

Конечно, можно вспомнить и другие английские названия цветов, похожих на синий, но они очень редко употребляются. А *blue* кроме основного значения в определённом контексте будет означать "я грустен, я печален". (То есть, шесть слов в русском против одного в английском)

Что по поводу синонимов... Русский язык ими очень богат. А если взять вместе синонимы, омонимы (все виды и проявления), паронимы и сравнить их с такой же группой из английского языка, ещё неизвестно, у кого их окажется больше. А вот что точно, так это то, что мы описать реальность вокруг нас можем действительно гораздо красочнее и богаче. Достаточно взять инверсию, удачно ввернуть метафору и припорошить всё синонимами... Ну, а у них чаще встречаются каламбуры и игра слов, потому что слова многозначнее... Неизвестно, достоинство это или недостаток языка, если бы можно было так выражаться.

Светлана Григорьевна сравнивала языки с мозаикой или витражом: из маленьких кусочков (обладающих своим цветом, формой, толщиной) языка состоит общая картина - культура. Если попытаться взять один кусочек и переставить в другую картину, то ничего даже и не получится: нельзя даже просто запихать неподходящую по размеру деталь в "правильный" проём. Поэтому "идентичные" понятия будут "выглядеть" в разных языках=культурах совсем по-разному. И, собственно говоря, не будут они одинаковыми: что для англичанина наша *рука*: *arm* или *hand*?

В общем, вот. Не имеет смысл сравнивать количество слов, это нисколько не говорит о богатстве языка.

И, да, повторю уже прозвучавшую мысль, что мы заносим новые слова в словари гораздо медленнее и вдумчивее.

Comment: Переводы русского текста на английский, тоже обычно оказываются длиннее оригинала.

Comment: Если переводчики (с обеих сторон) попытались максимально точно передать всю образность и красоту текста, то - да. Думаю, большое количество слов уходит на "перевод" понятия одной культуры в понятие другой.

Comment: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11781/Соотношение-объёма-русского-и-английского-текста Вопрос на эту тему, если интересно.

Comment: Да, спасибо, интересное обсуждение.

Answer (score 3):

*Человек начинает различать предметы только тогда, когда у них появляются названия. Вот и получается: больше слов - богаче реальность?* (@Sibylla)

**Больше слов не всегда значит больше понятий. В английском есть огромное количество синонимов.**

Это является следствием того, что в современном английском смешались слова старого английского, французского, латинского и других языков.
В эпоху среднеанглийского языка (с 1066 года до конца XV века) на территории Англии имели хождение среднеанглийский,
старофранцузский (на нём говорила знать и осуществлялось управление, в том числе церковное), латинский язык (использовался при дворе, в церковной службе) и германские языки (торговля и торговые термины, профессиональная жизнь).
Многие слова из этих языков вошли в английский.

Comment: Эти синонимы обладают зачастую важными оттенками, то есть, можно сказать, обозначают разные понятия.

Comment: Как известно, синонимы синонимам рознь. :) А для более глубоких рассуждений нужно быть профессионалом, знатоком английских синонимов. На это не претендую.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь хорошо бы привести примеры английских слов, которые не переводятся на русский одним словом. Учитывая, что слов в английском языке в три раза больше, чем в русском, привести такие примеры — задача не особенно трудная. Скажем, по пять примеров существительных, прилагательных и глаголов. Для начала, а там посмотрим.

Comment: Любую книгу можно перевести с одного языка на другой, при этом несколько разных  английских слов заменят одним русским с обобщенным значением. Вообще эта статья начинается с информации о количестве слов, обозначающих  цвета в разных языках. Есть племя, которое различает только красный и желтый цвет. Если вы оденете желтую рубашку  и синие джинсы, то они скажут, что вы нарядились во всё жёлтое.

Comment: Получается, что в каждой теме количество слов определяет количество различаемых предметов, оттенков чувств и т.д.  Возможно, к примеру, у них больше  названий для одежды, обуви,  а у нас только ботинки, туфли да сапоги.  Человек начинает  различать предметы только тогда, когда у них появляются названия. Вот и получается: больше слов - богаче реальность?

Comment: Нужны конкретные примеры: названия одежды, обуви, цветов и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Пишу только потому, что не нашел у предыдущих отвечающих конкретных ответов на конкретные вопросы.

> Если сравнить русский и английский словари, то видно, что мы
>   проигрываем по числу слов английскому языку...

Да, в основном это так. Можно спорить по поводу конкретных цифр, но если сравнивать по словнику, то, безусловно, количество вариантов перевода с русского на английский конкретного слова обычно больше, чем в обратную сторону.
Этот факт известен и не подлежит переосмыслению.

> 150 тысяч слов, среди которых не менее 30% заимствованных слов...

А вот здесь уже начинаются натяжки. Какие слова считать заимствованиями? 
Все, кроме прямых индоевропейских? Так их 0,2-0,3%.
Доставшиеся от праславянского? Их не более 3% 
Из древнерусского? Этих поболее, но тоже явно не 70%.
Другими словами, в русском, как и почти во всех живых и развитых языках (кроме, может, китайского, там просто заимствования не приживаются), основной состав словника — заимствования разных этапов. 
Для чего я это говорю? Просто для того, чтобы высказать одну простую мысль. В английском заимствований не в пример больше. Потому и слов больше.
Вопрос этот не принципиален ровно до того момента, пока не начинаются сравнения в разных языках. Огромные пласты французской, голландской, норманнской и кельтской лексики. И вроде бы даже единичные докельтские (пиктские) слова имеются. 
Короче, тут ловить нечего.

> Получается, что реальность англоговорящих богаче по восприятию, чем у
>   русскоговорящих. И это значит, что ресурс (у нас, по-видимому!) в
>   понимании себя и мира есть, и большой.

А вот это уже, простите, полный бред. Мог бы показать несостоятельность идеи, но поскольку "духовность" (и прочие скрепы) весьма мало связаны с филологией, развивать эту мысль не буду. Просто за рамками темы.

Впрочем, как уже сказали, количество слов в языке не отражает количества понятий ими выражаемых. В немецком "слов" неизмеримо больше, поскольку едва ли не любая пара существительных допускает образования нового слова слиянием исходных. Да и не только пара... Но **понятий-то** больше не становится от того, что слова пишутся слитно...

> И потенциал реализации этого
>   ресурса тоже есть – ведь английские слова активно проникают в русский
>   язык".

Вот, пожалуй, единственная нетривиальная тема — о заимствованиях. Обогощают они язык или засоряют. Но у вас вопрос так не стоит, я не буду мыслию по древу растекаться. Если коротко, то ни то, ни другое. Надо просто принять как данность, что процесс идет.

//=====

Перебросился я репликами с МаркИз'ом — и вот что подумал.

> Получается, что реальность англоговорящих богаче по восприятию, чем у
>   русскоговорящих. И это значит, что ресурс (у нас, по-видимому!) в
>   понимании себя и мира есть, и большой.

Видимо, надо прежде всего понять, что тут означает сам термин "богатая по восприятию реальность". Очевидно, что вот мы с МИ трактуем это совершенно по-разному. Возможно, что у автора этого текста вообще своё собственное понимание этого. И не исключено, что в этом его понимании словарный запас действительно как-то коррелирует с богатством мировосприятия. Ну скажем, на уровне выразительности средств.